# Parsing package error on apk install

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I am trying to create a application (Barcode Scanner) and problem is when i am trying to install it on my android mobile, it gives an error parsing the package.
how can i solve it any idea please.

Thanks

Comment: have you intalled before.??

Comment: yes is it signed apk.

Comment: no i m installing it first time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insure that you don't use methods from API greater than `minSdkVersion` (defined in AndroidManifest.xml) and your device supports this API

Comment: You can check docs about API levels here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: when i run that into emulator its running but in case when i installing it into my android cellphone then its giving error  parsing of pacakge

Comment: which versions of android OS do your device and emulator have?

Comment: In my project it is 17 and in that library project it is 7 so is it a problem ??

Comment: yeah, try to change minSdk in your project to 7. If your device has android 2.1+ then it should support it

Comment: i tried it but still it gives same problem is there any version problem in my android mobile??

Comment: probably you use some methods from API version greater than 7 despite the declared minSdkVersion. Try to check your IDE warnings

Comment: okys can you give me some link by that i can rebuild a BarcodeScanner using PhoneGap for android.